# android openGL ES onDrawFrame is not repeating

Tags: android, opengl-es

First of all, I learned it from "TheNewBoston", so I know that it should work.

I made the cube as Travis did, I tried to add rotation to the cube with this code:

```
gl.glRotatef(100, 1, 2, 0);
```

But it rotated just once.
I saw in the tutorial that the cube should keep rotate.

My question is:
Why the cube rotated just one time, there is something that i need to add?

Thanks for the help.

p.s. The tutorial: [TheNewBoston 182 android tutorial - 3D rotation](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=6&number=182)

Comment: You should be using OpenGL ES 2.0 anyway...

Comment: nevermind, i got the answer, i should use variable and change it. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind, i just got it :)
you should use variable for the degrees.
any loop cycle to change his value, it is working :)

thanks anyway.